# How to delete product in users cart if i deleted it in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do i delete the product without causing any errors on the users side.Am getting an error saying nonetype object has no attribute price
This is my views code for the cart page

```
def cartData(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
```

this is my product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price=models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    discount_price=models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the product in your list.
I would check if the product name is equal to None, then I remove the product in the list.

Indeed, when you remove from admin, the product becomes None because it doesn't exist anymore. So you need to remove from your list.